# call the change event after the SELECT is populated?

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

So, I have a dynamically generated SELECT, that gets populated from a PHP-mySQL table.
I also have an on change event for the select, that deals with the times the user changes the selected value on the page. When change event is fired, I populate 3 input boxes with values from that select option.

It all works just fine, except, when I enter (or refresh) the page with the SELECT, the SELECT gets populated, but the onChange event does not fire. Actually I am sure that the onchange gets fired, but that happens before the SELECT is populated so there are no values to offer.
What can I do? **How can I call the change event after** the **SELECT is populated properly** from php?

My code for onChange is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myselect').change(function(){
      var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
      $('#pux').val(selected.data('foo'));
    }).change();
});
```

So basically, I want an input with the name and id = **pux** to be filled with the data-foo value of the select option. I mean, the structure of the options of the select is like:

```
<option id="1" value="whatever" data-foo="something_important">First option</option>
```

and of course the destination input box is:

```
<input type="text" name="pux" id="pux" value="0" />
```

Like I said: the event works great on manual change of the select, but on page show (document.ready) the pux input box is set to nothing... empty...
I want to be able to **get the change event to fire after the select is populated**. Since , after the select gets populated, **the select box selects automatically the first option and displays it**.

- I tried to use $(document).**on("change"**, function()... outside of document.ready but it's no change
- I also tried to set the value of the input, right after populating the SELECT from php but id does not seem to work. Either I place the code in the wrong place, or I do not know what to think anymore...

My code that calls the php in order to populate it is:

```
$('#myselect').toggle('fast', function(){
  $(this).html(ajaxloader);
  $(this).toggle('fast', function(){
    $.get(loadurl, function(data){
      $('#myselect').html(data);
      $('#myselect').selectmenu("refresh",true);
    },'html');
// and here I placed my assignment
    var selx  = $('#myselect').find('option:selected');
    $('#pux').val(selx.data('foo'));
  });
});
```

Still nothing...

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing there's ajax somewhere in this, like in the `selected.data()` function that you're not showing us ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the change event gets populated? Show the code. (Can you not just call `.change()` from the end of the population function?)

Comment: @PSL - I did mention that above. I did try it there, but it seems the dynamic options are not in the SELECT yet when that event fires :(

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried it from the end of the populator function too, same result.

Comment: @adeneo ... I edited the question and added the populator function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it appears that populating a select list dynamically does not call the change() event. Therefore, you may want to consider extracting your change event handler into a separate procedure:

```
function populatePux() {
  var selected = $('#myselect option:selected');
  $('#pux').val(selected.data('foo'));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myselect').change(populatePux);
});
```

You can then run `populatePux()` immediately after #myselect is populated, in the function you use for that particular process.

Comment: I already tried that. I did not use a separate function, I just added the contents of the function at the end of the populator function.  Also I tried it your way. I defined the function and called it after populating the select. No change..

Comment: What happens if you put the call to populatePux inside the $.get call? By my reading of your updated code, it may be running the function before the [adynchronous] call has completed.

Comment: Awesome. You are right, that did it. I placed the call inside the get call and now it works like a charm. **Thank you very much**